# Gluing integral curves of two smooth vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two smooth vector fields defined in a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold $M$, with $X$ and $Y$ never vanishing simultaneously. Say $\gamma:[0,\varepsilon_1]\to M$ is an integral curve of $X$ and $\rho:[0,\varepsilon_2]\to M$ is an integral curve of $Y$, with $\gamma(\varepsilon_1)=\rho(0)$.

Can I construct two smooth functions $\alpha,\beta \in C^{\infty}(M)$ such that the vector field $\alpha X+\beta Y$ has an integral curve that joins $\gamma(0)$ and $\rho(\varepsilon_2)$?

The problem, of course, is with the point of intersection $\gamma(\varepsilon_1)=\rho(0)$. I tried putting a coordinate patch around that point and using the tubular flow theorem to glue the two curves, but couldn't make it work.

Also, is it possible to do it without both functions ($\alpha$ and $\beta$) vanishing simultaneously?

I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Since no-one has commented yet: it suffices to find an embedded smooth curve $\sigma$ joining the two endpoints with $\dot \sigma \in \mathrm{span}(X,Y)$, since if $\dot \sigma = \alpha X + \beta Y$ then any smooth extensions $\tilde \alpha, \tilde \beta$ will make $\sigma$ an integral curve of $\tilde\alpha X + \tilde\beta Y$. When $X,Y$ span an integrable distribution finding such a curve is easy. In the non-integrable case, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis If $\sigma$ is a curve in the foliation (assuming the distribution is integrable) joining the two points, is there an easy way to see that the coefficients $\alpha X+\beta Y = \dot \sigma$ are smooth functions (assuming of course the curve $\sigma$ is smooth)?

Comment: $X,Y$ is a smooth frame for the leaf of the foliation, and the coefficients $\alpha,\beta$ can be picked out by applying the corresponding dual frame (which is smooth) to $\dot \sigma$. Boils down to matrix inversion being smooth on $GL(2,\mathbb R)$ if you want to get dirty in coordinates.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Oh, I see it! Thank you, you've been most helpful! The integrable case is enough for me, but I'll leave the question here just in case.